# Как удалить лишние пробелы в строке(StringBuffer)

Tags: java

Как удалить лишние пробелы в строке, если она типа `StringBuffer`? Важно не использовать переход в `String`.

допустим строка:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("this        is   а    test message");
```

должна превратиться в:

```
"this is a test message"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пробегаем по `StringBuffer` и перемещаем в начало все непробельные символы. Если встречаем пробел, и он идет первым, также перемещаем его и запоминаем индекс. Все последующие пробелы игнорируем. При встрече непробельного символа сбрасываем индекс пробела.

```
static void removeWhiteSpaces(StringBuffer sb) {
    int end = 0;
    int spaceIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length; i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(i))) {
            sb.setCharAt(end++, sb.charAt(i));
            spaceIndex = -1;
        } else if (spaceIndex < 0) {
            sb.setCharAt(end++, sb.charAt(i));
            spaceIndex = i;
        }
    }

    sb.setLength(end);
}
```

Comment: Вместо `sb.delete(end, sb.length);` можно использовать `sb.setLength(end)`, это будет немного быстрее работать.

Comment: @OleGG да, действительно. Обновил ответ, спасибо.

Comment: @andreycha но, он удаляет все пробелы, а мне надо чтобы удалял, если их 2 или 3, например.

Comment: @thundermind вы спросили "Как удалить лишние пробелы?", причем тут их количество? Поясните подробнее задачу тогда.

Comment: @andreycha, к сожалению сайт стер лишние пробелы в примере.
Задача следующая:
есть строка типа StringBuffer, и надо удалить лишние пробелы, если их больше одного.

Comment: @thundermind т.е. если подряд идет несколько пробелов, то вам нужно оставить только один? (Для отображения нескольких пробелов в вопросе можно использовать `&nbsp;`)

Comment: @andreycha да, именно так :)

Comment: @thundermind обновил ответ, а заодно и ваш вопрос.

Comment: @andreycha огромное спасибо, очень помогли :)

Comment: @thundermind не за что. Можете пометить ответ как верный.

Comment: см. [How to remove duplicate white spaces in string using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958955/how-to-remove-duplicate-white-spaces-in-string-using-java)

Comment: я в `java` не силен, по этому задам вопрос, почему нельзя сделать так:
`new String(" this     is a    test message   ").trim().replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")` ? Зачем решать в лоб через перебор?

Comment: @Invision можно. Я просто не люблю регэкспы (потому что не умею их готовить). Вы зря удалили свой ответ, можете его оставить как альтернативу.